# What does setting libname to "..." do in SAS?

Tags: sas

What does it mean when someone sets a libname to "..." in SAS?

```
libname ex "...";
```

I am looking at someone's old code and when I run this I get the following errors.

```
ERROR: Invalid physical name for library EX.
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.
```

Sorry, I am new to SAS. All insight would be appreciated!

Comment: The documentation is always your starting point. A Libname is a pointer to a directory that contains files, usually where you want to save SAS datasets or sometimes SAS programs. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/69738/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1nk65k2vsfmxfn1wu17fntzszbp.htm

Comment: SAS provides training, free e-course to learn programming as well as short YouTube tutorials. See support.sas.com/training/tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What "..." is meant to imply is that you should set the libname to something appropriate to your project/environment.  The ellipsis (`...`) is used to suggest something that is left out, in this case to be filled in by you.

This is pretty common in example code, where a libname statement is necessary (particularly if using a libname option) and the example-creator doesn't want to specify an actual path (which might not actually exist).

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The directory path specified inside `"..."` is invalid = directory does not exist.